# After reconfigured Data, can no longer access values

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an edit for that use to work perfectly unit someone on the team reconfigured that data payload for the API, now having a nested entity called "data". Here is what the new returning payload looks like:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "data": {
       "name": "Tank 101",
       "dimensions": "76.0 x 90.5 x 101.0",
    }
}
```

Originally before the entities were nested inside if a data entity I would just call to *values.name* and *values.dimensions* on my Details and Edit pages to access the values.  After the data reconfiguration, I updated to *values.data.name* and *values.data.dimensions*.  This worked perfectly for my details page and to populate the existing values for my edit page, but my edit page throws this error on the code I use to disable my submit:

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')***

The line of code throwing the error is:

```
  const disabled = (!values.data.name || !values.data.dimensions );
```

Which I use to disable the submit button id the value is undefined or null.

**Here is my Form:**

```
const [values, setValues] = React.useState({} as any);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${detailsUrl + selectedRecord.id}`);
      setValues( res.data );
    } catch (error) {
      setValues( error.response.data );
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);


// Conditions to disable submit button
  const disabled = (!values.data.name || !values.data.dimensions ); 

// Form
return
 <>
 {values.status !== 1 ? <DataError /> :
  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
        <Controls.Input  
            type='text'
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            name='name'
            label='Equipment Name'
            value={values.data.name}
        /> 
        <Controls.Input  
            type='text'
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            name='dimensions'
            label='Equipment Dimensions'
            value={values.data.dimensions}
        />  
        <Button
            type='submit'
            text='Submit'
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            disabled={disabled}
        />
    </Form>
    }
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

change `setValues( res.data )` to  `setValues( res )`
or

```
const disabled = (!values.data.name || !values.data.dimensions );
```

to

```
 const disabled = (!values.name || !values.dimensions );
```

Comment: I had 'res.data' in my Axios call previously when I was only calling to 'values.name' and it work perfectly. I was grabbing the data element of the response

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `React.useState` to initialize values with an empty object `({})`, the data property inside values is initially `undefined`, which is causing the error when you try to access `values.data.name` and `values.data.dimensions` in the initial render.

You can either set the initial state of values with the required structure, including the `data` property, or just add a check before accessing the nested properties

```js
const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
  data: {
    name: '',
    dimensions: '',
  },
});

const disabled = !values.data.name || !values.data.dimensions;
```

or

```js
const disabled = !values?.data?.name || !values?.data?.dimensions
```

Comment: This seems like a logical wat to handle it, but rather than have just 2 values, the API call is returning 30+ values, and setting initial values for all of them will be quite a bit.  Also, I didn't have to do it originally before my teammate changed the API and nested the values inside a 'data' value.  I wanted to set a check to only set the const as long as the status value was 1, but I couldn't figure out how to write it without getting logic errors.

Comment: @Mtullis as mentionned if you don't want to do that you still can do this `const disabled = !values?.data?.name || !values?.data?.dimensions;`